# Cannot modify the text of this element in a variable using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom

I got this easy code can't get it to work. Please help me!

```
<p id="p">
   Test
</p>

<script>
  var p_tag = document.getElementById("p");

  document.p_tag.innerHTML = "Hey";
</script>
```

Comment: please clarify what you are trying  to do.

Comment: Remove `document.` from the second line. Just use `p_tag.innerHTML`.

Comment: Please improve the title

Comment: the `document.` is already in the var, you don't need it again in front of the var.

Comment: Just remove 'document.' In the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the document. from before p_tag.

```
<script>
  var p_tag = document.getElementById("p");

  document.p_tag.innerHTML = "Hey";
</script>
```

Change to:

```
<script>
  var p_tag = document.getElementById("p");

  p_tag.innerHTML = "Hey";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

probably you are trying to do this

```
<p id="p">
   Test
</p>

<script>
  var p_tag = document.getElementById("p");
    p_tag.innerHTML = "Hey";
</script>
```

the `document` is already in the var, so don't duplicate it

Answer (score 1):

`p_tag` is a variable. You declared it as such. It’s already an `HTMLElement` referring to the existing `<p id="p">Test</p>`, so you have to use it like this:

```
p_tag.innerHTML = "Hey";
```

`document` doesn’t have anything to do with your declared variables, so there won’t be a `p_tag` property on `document`.

You can also simplyfy this to:

```
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "Hey";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="p">
   Test
</p>

<script>
  var p_tag = document.getElementById("p");// get link of html element where id="p" 

  It is error: document.p_tag.innerHTML = "Hey";
  It is valid code: p_tag.innerHTML = "Hey";// overwrites the entire contents inside the element to "Hey"
</script>
```